How to encrypt my react-native app before backup?
I have the task of Encrypting my React Native app before it is backed up, to protect sensitive information. How can I do that?
I'm new to React Native and I'm having a hard time finding an answer to this.
Some ChatGPT recommendations include using libraries like react-native-encrypted-storage or react-native-sensitive-info but then he shows me ways of encrypting some data, let's say a user identity document, but I need a more global approach, like encrypting the whole app before backup, if possible. I'm open to advice, maybe there is an easier way.
Anyways, I need further clarification of the step by step process, please.
